# d3 change bar chart color according to height

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

I created a bar chart in a way that I can expand or reduce the height of every bar with mouse drag and it changes the data automatically according to the dragged value. I want to change the color in a way that every bar gets more red when I expand its height and more green when I reduce its height.
How can I achieve it ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    .selection {
      fill: steelblue;
      fill-opacity: 1;
    }

    body {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <body >
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var data = [
        { index: 0, value: 18 },
        { index: 1, value: 20 },
        { index: 2, value: 19 },
      ];

      var widthY = 550,
        heightY = 600,
        delim = 4;

      var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 21]).rangeRound([heightY, 0]);

      var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).rangeRound([0, widthY]);

      var svgY = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", widthY)
        .attr("height", heightY)
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .append("g");

      var brushY = d3
        .brushY()
        .extent(function (d, i) {
          return [
            [x(i) + delim / 2, 0],
            [x(i) + x(1) - delim / 2, heightY],
          ];
        })
        .on("brush", brushmoveY)
        .on("end", brushendY);

      var svgbrushY = svgY
        .selectAll(".brush")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .append("g")
        .call(brushY)
        .call(brushY.move, function (d) {
          return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
        });

      svgbrushY
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return scaleY(d.value) + 25;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
          return x(i) + x(0.5);
        })
        .attr("dx", "-.60em")
        .attr("dy", -5)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function (d) {
          return d3.format(".2")(d.value);
        });

      function brushendY() {
        if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
        if (!d3.event.selection) {
          svgbrushY.call(brushY.move, function (d) {
            return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
          });
        }
      }

      function brushmoveY() {
        if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
        if (!d3.event.selection) return;

        var d0 = d3.event.selection.map(scaleY.invert);
        var d = d3.select(this).select(".selection");

        d.datum().value = d0[0];

        update();
      }

      function update() {
        svgbrushY
          .call(brushY.move, function (d) {
            return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
          })
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return scaleY(d.value) + 25;
          })
          .text(function (d) {
            return d3.format(".2")(d.value);
          });
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your bars are currently blue, as I'm certain you are aware, but do you wish for the bars to slowly become less blue and more green/red as they are made taller or shorter than how they started? Or do  you want all bars of a given height, dragged or otherwise, to have the same color, something between red and green but never blue(ish)?

Comment: I want that every bar begin with a color according to its height for example if the bar is a 1 in its initial state then it's more green but if it is 20 in its initial state it shows red (it's not supposed to be blue at all)

Comment: Thought that was the case - but you never know, the relative to starting position could be applicable in specific cases. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need a scale:

```
 var color = d3.scaleLinear().domain(scaleY.domain()).range(["lightgreen","crimson"])
```

Now we need to update the color of the bars on drag in the update function:

```
 svgbrushY.selectAll(".selection").style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
```

That gets us almost all the way there - but the colors are not right initially. The creation of the brush breaks the data binding for the .selection rectangle: if you log

```
svgbrushY.selectAll(".selection").each(function(d) { console.log(d); })
```

You'll notice that the datum doesn't have the value property before being dragged. So we can add it ourselves initially and style the bar the same as we do during the update function:

```
   svgbrushY.select(".selection")
     .datum(d=>d)
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
```

That should give us something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    .selection {
      fill-opacity: 1;
    }

    body {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <body >
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var data = [
        { index: 0, value: 18 },
        { index: 1, value: 20 },
        { index: 2, value: 19 },
      ];

      var widthY = 550,
        heightY = 200,
        delim = 4;

      var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 21]).rangeRound([heightY, 0]);

      var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).rangeRound([0, widthY]);
      
      var color = d3.scaleLinear().domain(scaleY.domain()).range(["lightgreen","crimson"])

      var svgY = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", widthY)
        .attr("height", heightY)
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .append("g");

      var brushY = d3
        .brushY()
        .extent(function (d, i) {
          return [
            [x(i) + delim / 2, 0],
            [x(i) + x(1) - delim / 2, heightY],
          ];
        })
        .on("brush", brushmoveY)
        .on("end", brushendY);

      var svgbrushY = svgY
        .selectAll(".brush")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .append("g")
        .call(brushY)
        .call(brushY.move, function (d) {
          return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
        });
        
       svgbrushY.select(".selection")
         .datum(d=>d)
         .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
        
       
       svgbrushY
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return scaleY(d.value) + 25;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
          return x(i) + x(0.5);
        })
        .attr("dx", "-.60em")
        .attr("dy", -5)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function (d) {
          return d3.format(".2")(d.value);
        });

      function brushendY() {
        if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
        if (!d3.event.selection) {
          svgbrushY.call(brushY.move, function (d) {
            return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
          });
        }
      }

      function brushmoveY() {
        if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
        if (!d3.event.selection) return;

        var d0 = d3.event.selection.map(scaleY.invert);
        var d = d3.select(this).select(".selection");

        d.datum().value = d0[0];

        update();
      }
      
   

      function update() {
        svgbrushY
          .call(brushY.move, function (d) {
            return [d.value, 0].map(scaleY);
          })
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return scaleY(d.value) + 25;
          })
          .text(function (d) {
            return d3.format(".2")(d.value);
          });
   
           svgbrushY.selectAll(".selection").style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })          
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(scaled down for snippet view)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add x and y axises with numbers in this case ?